# Link character device to pty with socat

Tags: embedded, socat, pty

I have a "regular character device" - not sure of the proper naming - that doesn't support `ioctl` on an embedded device (`/dev/appvcom`). I need to connect to it with an application that uses some `ioctl` commands when connecting and fails. I'm fairly sure the commands don't do anything important, so I'm trying to "wrap" the device in a `pty`.

Here's what I tried:

```
# socat -dd pty /dev/appvcom
2020/03/05 18:45:13 socat[1616] N PTY is /dev/pts/1
2020/03/05 18:45:13 socat[1616] N opening character device "/dev/appvcom" for reading and writing
2020/03/05 18:45:13 socat[1616] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [5,5] and [7,7]
```

And that creates a `pty` on `/dev/pts/1` or similar. I can now connect with `screen` to the newly created `pty`. The problem is reading from the `pty` works fine, but writing doesn't seem to work. I've also confirmed it by echoing to the device and `pty` directly.

```
# echo -e 'AT\r' > /dev/appvcom    // works, can see OK reply from device in cat or screen
# echo -e 'AT\r' > /dev/pts/1      // no reply :(
```

I've tried various `socat` options on the device, no luck so far. Not even sure if this is the proper way to do it or if there's another tool just for this.

Comment: How do you know that those ioctls don't do anything important? Better post a `strace -fe trace=ioctl`. Anyway, try making `/dev/pts/1` raw with `stty -F /dev/pts/1 raw`.

Comment: @mosvy - you're right, I don't know for sure. It just tries to get it's attributes, strace: `[pid  1406] ioctl(13, TCGETS, 0xb5c3fbd4) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)`. Raw mode didn't help.

Comment: That could be the app just checking if the file is a tty. (via `isatty(3)`). If the app insists on a tty, it may want to do some serial ioctls on it (like `TIOCMBIS`). Try strace-ing the application when successful, to see what ioctls it is actually using. When you say that raw mode didn't help, you mean the `echo -e 'AT\r' > /dev/pts/1`?

Comment: Yes, tested both that and screen. Found the source: https://github.com/haha8x/asterisk-chan-dongle-16/blob/master/chan_dongle.c#L248 - pretty sure it just sets some settings and then proceeds with the AT commands. This module was made for USB dongles, but my modem is built in the chip. Does have both an AT command port and an audio port.

Comment: The failing call is probably `tcgetattr` a few lines up. I didn't notice it in `strace` the first time, but there's also a failing `TIOCEXCL` which matches the code.

Comment: Got it working with some really ugly hacks, so the software does work without ioctl. I made a `pty` to `pty`, hooked the software up to one end and wrote a bash script that reads the other end line by line and echoes it into the device. Still hoping to solve it with just socat.

Comment: That means that `socat` is the culprit.

Comment: Try `socat -dd pty,link=<path>,raw,echo=0,wait-slave /dev/appvcom` and use `<path>` as the device for your application ... note that `/dev/appvcom` won't be opened until your application opens `<path>` (thanks to `wait-slave` option).